# Instagram API subscription returns 400 bad request

Tags: java, api, instagram, instagram-api, apigee

Ok, I've been trying this for quite some time now and I just can't make this call work.

I'm trying to make an user subscription with the [new instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/), but it doesn't matter how I try it, it returns the same result:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "error_type": "APISubscriptionError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Unable to reach callback URL \"http://28447bf9.ngrok.io/instagram/subscription\"."
  }
}
```

The callback URL is a valid URL (using ngrok as you can see).

I have my endpoint ready to receive the callback:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/instagram/subscription", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object verifySubscription(
            @RequestParam(value = "hub.mode") String mode,
            @RequestParam(value = "hub.challenge") final String challenge,
            @RequestParam(value = "hub.verify_token", required = false) String verifyToken) {
        return new Object() {
            @JsonValue
            @JsonRawValue
            public String getValue() {
                return challenge;
            }
        };
    }
```

I have a valid access token and the client ID and secrets are correct.

I've tried different ways to make this call. Currently, the way I try to make the post call is the way [Apigee](https://apigee.com/console/instagram) does, WHICH WORKS! (I mean, sometimes.)

This is the request Apigee does:
[image]

So it adds the **verify_token**, **client_id** and **client_secret** in the URL and the rest of the parameters as the post body. Should also be noted that the **access_token** is added to the URL since I'm logged.

Given that, I've tried (using org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:4.5.1, lastest version as of now):

```
Content content = Request.Post(
                    String.format("%s?access_token=%s&verify_token=%s&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s", 
                            INSTAGRAM_SUBSCRIBE_URL, 
                            accessToken, 
                            accessToken,
                            clientID,
                            clientSecret
                    ))
                    .bodyString("aspect=media;callback_url=" + subscribeCallbackURI + ";object=user;", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .execute()
                    .returnContent();
```

Needless to say I was first trying to make the request without providing the access_token in the url, but with the same result.

I've tried making this same request without using the fluent API.

Also tried make the call directly with both Postman and [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/)... with no success.

It's good to note that Apigee is still referring to the [old Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/deprecated/realtime/), but at least this user subscription is still the same.

Any advice? I know the Instagram API is quite unstable, but I should be able to get a successful response once in a while (like I do when using Apigee).

Comment: Have you tried using **https** instead?

Comment: I'm getting tunnel not found on that callback url...

Comment: @remus my application is down now, thats why.

Comment: @mansilladev, actually no, will try it out!